# I would like to make that js-fullheight as an auto height

Tags: javascript, jquery

The code I used is below, but when I shrink the screen it goes to hide the other div below

```
var fullHeight = function() {
    if ( !isMobile.any() ) {
        $('.js-fullheight').css('height', $(window).height());
        $(window).resize(function(){
            $('.js-fullheight').css('height', $(window).height());
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: Sorry, may you rephrase your question? What's an actual problem?